# Pegar o nome de um item dentro de uma array em strings.xml

Tags: android, array, xml

Eu tenho a seguinte array:

```
<array name="Codes">
        <item name="Vermelho">e74c3c</item>
        <item name="Azul">3498db</item>
        <item name="Rosa">FC14E5</item>
        <item name="Roxo">8e44ad</item>
        <item name="Amarelo">f1c40f</item>
        <item name="Laranja">d35400</item>
        <item name="Verde">2ecc71</item>
        <item name="Cinza">95a5a6</item>
    </array>
```

e tenho uma variável que guarda o código da cor

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(codes));
this.colorCode = "#" + codes[0];
```

como eu poderia pegar o name="" ?

Comment: Onde esse xml está salvo?

Comment: strings.xml, padrão do android

Comment: `String[] some_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_string_array)` não deu certo?

Comment: Isso pegaria o código da cor, que é o que eu já tenho, eu gostaria de pegar o nome do item da array, no caso, Vermelho

Comment: Ah sim, você vai precisar de um parser de xml, felizmente o android também [possui isso](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html). Veja o link como referencia até que alguem te responda.

Comment: Ok, vou dar uma lida, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,
Uma solução para o seu problema seria criar um outro array que tivesse em seus valores os nomes das cores. Como no Exemplo

```
<array name="Codes">
        <item name="Vermelho">e74c3c</item>
        <item name="Azul">3498db</item>
        <item name="Rosa">FC14E5</item>
        <item name="Roxo">8e44ad</item>
        <item name="Amarelo">f1c40f</item>
        <item name="Laranja">d35400</item>
        <item name="Verde">2ecc71</item>
        <item name="Cinza">95a5a6</item>
    </array>
<array name="Colors">
            <item name="Vermelho">Vermelho</item>
            <item name="Azul">Azul</item>
            <item name="Rosa">Rosa</item>
            <item name="Roxo">Roxo</item>
            <item name="Amarelo">Amarelo</item>
            <item name="Laranja">Laranja</item>
            <item name="Verde">Verde"</item>
            <item name="Cinza">Cinza</item>
        </array>
```

Desta forma você consegue pegar o nome apenas usando o mesmo índice.